# What is wrong with this analogy finding equality between two formulae of average velocity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, mathematics, calculus

I have seen several questions on this confusion. Most are related with the issue of using variable acceleration. So here is an example where I am using a constant acceleration, but it still seems to be different for two formulae. Where the reasoning goes wrong?

I have made up a very basic problem like this. A body is moving with constant acceleration of 1m/s^2 . It moves for 4 seconds. And here is the data table for each second of it's movement

| time(sec) | speed accelerating @1m/s^2 | displacement |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0m/s | 0 m |
| 1 | 1m/s | 1 m |
| 2 | 2m/s | 1+2=3m |
| 3 | 3m/s | 1+2+3=6m |
| 4 | 4m/s | 1+2+3+4=10m |

So with initial velocity of 0 and final velocity of 4m/s the body covers a total distance of 10 m

So average velocity using formulae
avg_velocity = total_displacement/total_time

=> 10 / 4 = 2.5 m/s

And,

Average velocity using formula =  u+v/2

(0 + 4)/ 2 = 2 m/s

Why they are different.

Comment: Your values for  displacements are wrong. After one second the displacement is 0.5 m, for example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your displacement values are wrong. In 4 seconds, the total displacement is 8m, so both average velocity formulas give the same result.

Why your displacement is wrong? Think of the first second of movement. The final velocity is $1 m/s$, but during the interval the velocity is less than that, so final displacement can't be $1 m$ yet. The average velocity during that first second is $0.5 m/s$, that's why the displacement is $0.5m$. The average velocity during the first two seconds is $1 m/s$, that's why the displacement after two seconds is $1 m/s \cdot 2 s = 2 m$, etc.

| time(sec) | speed accelerating @1m/s^2 | displacement |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0m/s | 0.0 m |
| 1 | 1m/s | 0.5 m |
| 2 | 2m/s | 2.0 m |
| 3 | 3m/s | 4.5 m |
| 4 | 4m/s | 8.0 m |

[image]

The formula for constant acceleration $a$ is $r = r_0 + v_0 \cdot t + \frac{1}{2} \cdot a \cdot t^2$, where $r, r_0$ are final and initial position, $v_0$ is initial velocity and $t$ is time.

Comment: Why not use 0.999 instead of 0.5? 
Btw, you used the formula of (v+u)/2 to get 0.5 m . Can you get 0.5 m with the other formula total_displacement/total_time ?  With the later formula, which is simpler to understand, I see total displacement from 0 to 1 as 1 m. And total time from 0 to 1 as 1 sec. So average velocity comes out to be 1m/s . 

Also, how much logical it would be to say in plain English that a body has covered 0 to 0.5 m in 1 sec, strangely means velocity changed from 0 to 1m/s. Hence acceleration is 1m/s/s

Comment: @Vishwas the second paragraph of the answer explains why the total displacement in the first second *isn't* 1m. Can you explain which part of that still confuses you?

Comment: Of course you can use total displacement and total time to find average velocity. But based on the initial velocity and constant acceleration you defined, you're calculating total displacement wrong.

Comment: @MJD The only part that confused me was how come the distance becomes 0.5m even when the final velocity is 1m/s. But I think I understand now, it's because the initial velocity is zero. And velocity increases from zero to final value. It's not the same as final velocity since beginning. That results in half value of displacement. If initial velocity was same as final velocity then the resultant value would be 1m.


I have tried to add my own explanation as an answer on this page. Do you think what I understood is still wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Your method of calculating displacement is not quite correct, because you've assumed in each interval the speed is constant, when it is not.

What you are trying to do is integrate your speed to get the distance, or another way of saying this is find the area under the speed vs time graph.  Your value is wrong because you're using rectangles of width 1 s to find the area of a diagonal line graph.

If you want the maths, you need to do
$$x = \int_0^{4\text{ s}}v\,\text{d} t=\int_0^{4\text{ s}}at\,\text{d} t=\left[\frac{1}{2}at^2\right]_{t=0}^{t=4\text{ s}}=8\text{ m}$$
Then $8\text{ m}/4\text{ s}=2\text{ m/s}$.

If you're not familiar with integrals, don't worry, perhaps your familiar with suvat?  Notice the $\frac{1}{2}at^2$ above is the same as the one that appears in the relevant suvat equation:
$$s=ut+\frac{1}{2}at^2$$
where here $u=0$.

Answer (score -1):

I think I got some understanding finally. For why average velocity comes exactly half eg. Why it yields 0.5 meters but not 1 meter even when the final velocity has increased from 0 m/s to 1 m/s.

It seems basically it is because velocity increments by small amounts and not all in one go. And that causes smaller displacements that what it would be if the initial velocity was same as final velocity ( and not zero). And these small additions each instant of time creates a triangle. That has got half the value of the square/rectangle created with the same dimensions.

[image]